# WSL-2: Connect from Windows host machine to Ubuntu guest running PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ufw

I'm running PostgreSQL 10 on a Windows 10 WSL-2 installation of Ubuntu 18.04. I can start the service, connect to it locally from within Ubuntu with `psql`, and use it for local development. So far, so good!

I'd like to be able to connect to this instance from the host Windows OS, but can't connect. From Windows `cmd`, I've tried using telnet to see if I can connect to the NAT IP of the Ubuntu machine:

```sh
$ telnet 172.123.456.789 5432
Connecting To 172.31.175.251...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed
```

When I run Django's `runserver` on port 8000, however, I can connect:

```sh
$ telnet 172.123.456.789 8000
[connected, returns HTML]
```

I've tried checking to see if it was something in Ubuntu's firewall `ufw`, but it isn't running:

```sh
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Has anyone cracked this nut?

Comment: `listen_addresses = '*'`, restart, disable firewall.

Comment: That got it, thank you - not pretty, but effective. :)

Comment: Pretty? What's ugly about configuring PostgreSQL properly?

Comment: I was referring to having to bind to all addresses and disabling the firewall. :) Hopefully WSL-2 can get feature parity with Vagrant soon enough for VMs having fixed IPs.